# Rails 4 - strong parameters with Stripe, my attributes are not getting set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strip, strong-parameters

I'm making an app where I use `Stripe` as my payment solution. To manage events I use the gem `stripe_event`. In my `config/initializers/stripe.rb` class I want to create different objects when different events occurs. Like a new `Subscription.rb` object when new subscriptions gets created, and then assign the `Subscription` to a `Team`.

This is how I currently create `Subscriptions`:

```
def create_subscription_for_team(team, subscription)

  team.build_subscription(
    current_period_start: subscription.current_period_start, current_period_end: subscription.current_period_end,
    status: subscription.status, started_at: subscription.start
  )
  team.stripe_subscription_id = subscription.id
  team.save!

end
```

The params in this method is an existing local `Team` and `subscription` is a `JSON` dictionary from the `Stripe` api.

The data is correct, my objects gets saved and created, but the properties `does not` get set (they remain nil). So I suspect that it has something to do with `Rails 4 Strong Parameters`.

So, how and where should I whitelist the parameters I get from the Stripe API to be able to set the attributes?

Or, do you think it's something else that is the cause?

*Update*

The subscription object looks like this:

```
object: {
  "application_fee_percent": null,
  "id": "[id]",
  "start": 1417208073,
  "metadata": {}
  "plan":  
    {"id":"medium","interval":"month","name":"[name]","created":1416859741,"amount":    [amount],"currency":"usd","object":"plan","livemode":false,"interval_count":1,"metadata":   {},"statement_description":null},
    "discount": null,
    "object": "subscription",
  }
  "customer": "[id]",
  "status": "active",
  "current_period_start": 1416865643,
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
```

Comment: Which properties don't get set? `current_perioid_start` and friends? Strong parameters only apply in controllers so that doesn't look like the problem here.

Comment: The only parameter that seems to get set in the code above is: `team.stripe_subscription_id = subscription.id`, `subscription.status` is nil for example.

Comment: Where does `subscription` come from? Is that from Stripe? What's in it?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, it is from Stripe. I have updated my question with the test `subscription` data (from my logs `puts` in the method above, so I know that it actually is this data).

Comment: So `subscription` has what you expect and the `build_subscription` appears to work but creates a subscription that is mostly full of `nil`s, right? Anything going on in your `Subscription`?

Comment: I don't think so (but I will check). However, I just noticed that `status` was not nil.  So it seems like it's only my `datetime` attributes that  does not get set properly. The common thing with `subscription.id and subscription.status` it that they are not datetimes. The date I receive is as above: `1416865643`, and I'm using `PostgreSQL`, with datetime for eg. `started_at`, do I need to parse the dates somehow to save them properly?

Comment: Try manually converting the timestamps with something like `Time.at`, looks like the timestamps got converted to seconds-since-epoch to get them through JSON.

Comment: Thank you, that was it! Now the dates also gets saved, I used `Time.at` as you suggested.